# Parameter passing with const primitive reference and only primitive

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Is there any difference between these two usage?

**1.**

```
void Foo(const double &n)
{
   cout<< "Hello: " << n << endl;
}
```

**2.**

```
void Foo(double n)
{
   cout<< "Hello: " << n <<endl;
}
```

I'm looking for a general answer, not only for this context. (`1.` usage makes me confused.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the value of the parameter in the first snippet, in the second one you can.

Outside the function, they both remain the same, because the second one passes by value.

```
void Foo(const double &n)
{
   n = 3; //ERROR
}

void Foo(double n)
{
   n = 3; //OK
}
```

For non-basic types, it makes a difference performance-wise. If you pass by reference (`1.`), you pass the original object, not a copy. If you pass by value, a copy is created.

Comment: +1. Also in the first case, you can return the address of or a reference to the parameter if needed while in the second case, you can't because the parameter won't exist when the function exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a reference and the value that the reference refers to changes, that change will be visible through the reference. If you pass by value, the change won't be visible. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double x;

void Foo1(const double& n) {
    cout << n << endl;
    x = 23.0;
    cout << n << endl;
}

void Foo2(double n) {
    cout << n << endl;
    x = 23.0;
    cout << n << endl;
}

int main()
{
    x = 42.0;
    Foo1(x); // Will print 42.0, then 23.0

    x = 42.0;
    Foo2(x); // Will print 42.0 twice

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example that shows the difference between 'const double&' and 'double' types.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo1(const double &n)
{
    const_cast<double&>(n) = 10.0;  // <-- this code changes variable referenced by n
}

void foo2(double n)
{
    const_cast<double&>(n) = 10.0;  // <-- this code changes variable n
}

int main()
{
    double x = 12.0;
    foo1(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  // <-- this will print '10'

    x = 12.0;
    foo2(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  // <-- this will print '12'

    return (0);
}
```

In the first case you send a reference (almost the same as pointer) to variable 'x'. In the second case you send a copy of variable 'x'.